# Friedberg's definition of ordered basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading Friedberg's 4th edition linear algebra and in section 2.2 he gives the following definition of an Ordered Basis.

**Definition** - Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. An ordered basis for V is a basis for V endowed with a specific order. That is, an ordered basis for V is a finite sequence of linearly independent vectors in $V$ that generate $V$.

I'm pretty confused by this definition. The first part seems to say an ordered basis is an ordered basis. And the second part seems like the exact definition of a basis. The only difference seems to be that it's specifically for a finite dimensional space now.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part sentence in the definition says $V$ is a *sequence* of linearly independent vectors that generate $V$, while usually a basis is a *set* of such vectors. The difference is that in an ordered basis you can talk about the first vector in the basis, etc, while there are no such distinctions in a set basis. Ordered bases are useful when you want to make change of basis matrices to convert a vector in one basis notation to another, since different orders of the basis vector give different such matrices.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did not notice the term sequence instead of set. I intuitively knew what they were talking about, but I was having a hard time seeing how this definition was any different than that of a regular basis until you pointed that difference in language out to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If someone offers you breakfast, lunch, and dinner, don't you think it makes an awful lot of difference whether they are being offered specifically *in that order*, rather than all piled on your plate simultaneously?